# Java: HttpURLConnection Issues with IllegalStateArgument: Already Connected

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, illegalstateexception

This question seems clear what is happening: I already have a connection open, the problem is I don't know why.

Right now I'm just testing my http login and out.

Login:

```
HttpURLConnection con = openConnection(URLGenerator.getLoginURL(), true, true,"POST");
        String content = ...;
        writeToOutput(con, content);
        con.connect();
        String cookieVal = con.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        if(cookieVal != null)
        {
            sessionId = cookieVal.substring(0, cookieVal.indexOf(";"));
        }
        con.disconnect();
        return con.getResponseCode();
```

Logout:

```
    HttpURLConnection con = openConnection(URLGenerator.getLogoutURL(), true, true,"GET");
    String content = ...;
    writeToOutput(con, content);
    setCookies(con);
    con.connect();
    con.disconnect();
    return con.getResponseCode();
```

and for the code lovers the function OpenConnection (because I know the first thing people are going to ask is "where is this function"

```
public static final HttpURLConnection openConnection(URL url, boolean in, boolean out,String requestMethode) throws IOException{
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
        con.setDoInput(in);
        con.setDoOutput (out);
        if(requestMethode == null){
            requestMethode = "GET";
        }
        con.setRequestMethod(requestMethode);
        con.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return con;
    }
```

This is the function that triggers the **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected**

```
public static final void setCookies(HttpURLConnection con){
        if(sessionId != null)
        {
            con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionId);
        }
    }
```

What I don't get is why the connection is still open.

I even tried to call disconnect but it doesn't work.

I thought the principal was to set up a HttpURLConncetion object and do connect to execute the request, receive the result and that terminated the connection.

Any ideas?

Thanks Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set cookies (request header values) *before* you write to the request body. You can't change the request headers anymore when the first bit of the request body is been sent.

So, change

```
writeToOutput(con, content);
setCookies(con);
```

to

```
setCookies(con);
writeToOutput(con, content);
```

and this problem should disappear.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I didn't think it mattered the order (I was viewing it as an Object where you set the values and send :$ honest mistake for my understanding of urlconnection :D)

Comment: You're welcome. The `connect()` call is by the way unnecessary. Some `URLConnection` methods already implicitly do that. The `disconnect()` is also not strictly necessary. It will behind the scenes basically immediately kill the cached connection (which would be killed anyway when it expires).